# twitter carousel not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get carousel working but it is not. When I click the arrows the url become mypage.html#myCarousel but nothing happens. Can someone please point to what I am missing here.

Here is my html

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap_2.0.3.min.css" type="text/css">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap_2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#myCarousel').carousel();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span10">
                <h2>my carousel</h2>
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
                    <!-- Carousel items -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="active item">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="span8">
                                   <img src="some image" alt="" width="500">
                                </div>
                                <div class="span2">
                                    <p>
                                       some text
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="item">

                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="span8">
                                    <img src="some image" alt="" width="500">
                                </div>
                                <div class="span2">
                                    <p>
                                        Some Text
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include jQuery first, and the bootstrap js later so flip the loading order and it should work.